# How to remove key fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I know how to delete documents in a collection. i.e. `User.last.delete`

In the `User` document. I have the following keys: `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`.

Lets say , I decide to remove the key `last_name`. So I would have `first_name` and `gender` only. How would I go about this? Is this even possible?

I tried `User.last.last_name.delete` to no avail.

Comment: The question is tagged roby-on raild, but the title and body should reflect that the question is based on rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually trying to remove the column from the database, you should make a migration to remove the column.

If you are trying to change a record to not have a last name you could do something like `User.last.last_name = false` and then save it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `User.last.last_name = nil`?

Comment: Im using mongodb / mongoid. I don't think mongodb comes with migrations

Comment: I believe mongodb has an unset method for this: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24unset for this. The point of mongodb is to have a schemaless db. Having migrations defeats the purpose. Now, I need to figure out if mongoid supports the unset method

Comment: It seems this can be done in mongoid by using the delete method: http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/

Answer (score 31):

Using mongoid: 
User.last.unset('last_name') should do the trick.

Comment: Do you have to call save after this because it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the `last_name` field from the entire collection (from all the documents in the collection), you would do `User.all.unset('last_name')`